# Как посчитать количество совпадений

Tags: c#, discord

Есть текстовый файл с подобными строками. Так же есть словарь где содержатся никнеймы из текстового файла (После [RL] и до "won). Есть конструкция if, которая должна выводить текст если есть совпадения в словаре и текстовом файле. Совпадения ищутся по никнейму. В силу недостатка опыта в таких алгоритмах, я не смогу придумать внятного решения. В основном пробовал с помощью метода Contains из Systeam.IO (вообщем посмотрите код). Так же обязательно нужно вывести число таких совпадений, а это еще сложнее как по мне. Если у вас есть решение такой задачи, пожалуйста напишите его в ответах, буду очень благодарен)

```
[RL] Kirra won against 18 players!
[RL] Florence won against 18 players!
```

Словарь(часть)

```
["Florence#2042"] = "Florence",
```

А так же "обертка" той конструкции, которую я уже пробовал

```
switch (msg.Content)
        {
            case "!победы":
                {

                    Console.WriteLine("Данные запрошены...");
                    var daywins = readwins.ReadToEnd(); 
                    if (daywins.Contains(win_val))
                    {     
                        

                        
                        msg.Channel.SendMessageAsync($"{win_key} ");
                    }
                    break;

                }

        }

        return Task.CompletedTask;
```

Код словаря на всякий случай

```
Dictionary<string, string> username = new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        ["Ту́ва#0001"] = "Тану-Тува",
        ["Kirra#2014"] = "Kirra",
        ["Batyr12#2016"] = "Коноха",
        ["Маэстро Chara#7679"] = "Маэстро Chara",
        ["[RL] Dream#5378"] = "Dr.Yes",
        ["Loys#0101"] = "Loys",
        ["Florence#2042"] = "Florence",
        ["bоb 2.0#0666"] = "Bob",
        ["riezhé#9742"] = "RussianAncapistan",
        ["Someone#4514"] = "Someone",
        ["TomiokaSan#4145"] = "Rengoku",
        ["Мюнхенский Маппер#1337"] = "Мюнхен",
        ["DPK#7777"] = "DPK",
        ["Dr. Schnekker#0001"] = "Dartikul",
        ["Country#0101"] = "Country",
        ["blubyrd_aliya#4486"] = "Aliya",
        ["|__Kurt_Knispel__| [RL]#0297"] = "Deutschland",
        ["Hudy#8800"] = "Hudy",
        ["DGCHubby#1871"] = "DGCHubby#1871"
    };
```

Comment: Не понял, какие совпадения? Просто проверить сколько раз встречалось в файле то или иное слово? `var result = File.ReadAllLines("мойФайл.txt").Count(x=>x.Contains("Искомое слово"));`. Или я не так понял задачу?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Да, все правильно поняли

Comment: Так в чем проблема тогда?

Comment: @tym32167 Конечный результат должен быть: ключ словаря: сколько раз его значение встречается в файле

Comment: это хорошо, но вопрос то в чем? Конечный результат - это ваша задача, я спросил про то, что вас заблокировало, что вам непонятно? Сверху уже показали, как считать количество, берите и считайте.

Comment: @tym32167 Мне не понятно как сделать так, что бы ключ словаря выводился вместе с количеством совпадений в файле, потому что тот метод указанный выше, считает только сколько раз встречаются значения словаря, но не указывает к какому ключу принадлежит значение

Comment: держи: https://www.vitoshacademy.com/c-count-words-in-a-text-abc-analysis-for-linguists/

Comment: Ты можешь пройти по словарю через foreach, там у тебя будет и ключ и значение каждой записи словаря

Comment: И что вам мешает сделать нужный вывод я не пойму... Ну ок, допустим `var result = username.Select(x => (User: x.Value, Won: lines.Count(l => l.Contains(x.Value))));`. `lines` - это `File.ReadAllLines()`. Если нужен словарь, то преобразуйте еще и в словарь (но зачем?) `.ToDictionary(k => k.User, v => v.Won)`.